# Play Framework: How can I use a given certifcate for an HTTP WS.url call?

Tags: scala, rest, ssl, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a certificate from a REST services provider, and I need to tell an given HTTP get call to use it when contacting a given provider.  The codebase I'm working on used to use a third party library to achieve this, but I want leverage the timeout features and niceties of the WS.url call.

I've had a look at the API docs and the docs on the website, and I only unearthed a few clues, and those clues have so far not lead me to any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to approach it by adapting the SSLContext of the AsyncHttpClient.
The idea is to provide the client certificate with the underlying client. I assume you have a pkcs12 flying around.

It seems like that the AsyncHttpClientConfig cannot be updated as it is auto initialised. Therefore a new client should be instantiated and used.

The following should send off the request as stated with the SSLContext containing the pkcs12 file.

```
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore clientCert = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/conf/brazo.p12");

    clientCert.load(is, "brazo".toCharArray());
    kmf.init(clientCert, "brazo".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null,
            new SecureRandom());
    AsyncHttpClientConfig config = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setSSLContext(sc).build();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(config);

    String url = "https://your-url";
    Request req = new RequestBuilder().setUrl(url).setMethod("GET").build();
    client.executeRequest(req);
```

Sadly this goes away from Play! standard WS library.

Comment: sadly this fails with: 
Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException: Default SSLContext is initialized automatically
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:511)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:283)
 at com.plexq.apiproxy.ApplicationContext$.<init>(ApplicationContext.scala:25)
 at com.plexq.apiproxy.ApplicationContext$.<clinit>(ApplicationContext.scala)
 ... 10 more

Comment: I edited my answer. Seems like updating the SSLContext via init method was not possible. So creating a new client could be a way to approach it. Does that help you further now?

Comment: This is close to what I ended up doing, essentially I copied the play implementation into my own library space and tweaked it in a similar fashion.  Feels pretty suboptimal, perhaps I should consider writing an update for the play framework?